# Numbering with prefix of zero in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to echo out a number with zeroes at the beginning?

For example

```
<?php

$i = 0001;
$i++;
echo $i;

?>
```

And when it print out, I want it to be like.

```
0002
```

Is it possible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible. You can do this using [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) method. Basically, this method adds a given value till a required length is achieved.

A Basic example of this would be:

```
echo str_pad($i, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Here,

- `4` represents the output length
- `"0"` represents the string used to pad, till the length is achieved.

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/uWJfnICi) Example:**

> ```
> <?php
> $i = 0001;
> $i++;
> echo str_pad($i, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 1;
$i++;
printf("%04d", $i); // 0002
```

- [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) - output a formatted string
- `%04d` - echo a 4 digit number, pad with 0's

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo str_pad($i, 4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

read the documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 0001;
echo str_pad(++$input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```